# Typescript error on parent component for missing props on child component when using react redux connect

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, axios

App.tsx : Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IProps': getProjects, projects

I followed [this](https://www.carlrippon.com/strongly-typed-react-redux-code-with-typescript/) example (not sure if it's the best, but I'm having a hard time finding some good examples for using react, redux, typescript and async actions. With or without thunk, but seems thunk is what people are recommending? I'd just like to know why I get this error and some feedback about whether this is a good approach or not.

I just tried implementing a single project where I should fetch some projects from an api. But the parent component is complaining about not sending in props in to the child? :S

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { Projects } from "./features/Projects";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className='App-link'
          href='https://reactjs.org'
          target='_blank'
          rel='noopener noreferrer'
        >
          Learn React
        </a>

        <Projects />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

reducers.ts

```
import { IProjectState, ProjectActions } from "./types";
import { Reducer } from "react";

const initialProjectState: IProjectState = {
  projects: [],
};

export const projectReducer: Reducer<IProjectState, ProjectActions> = (
  state = initialProjectState,
  action: ProjectActions
): IProjectState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GettingProjects": {
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    }
    case "GotProjects": {
      return {
        ...state,
        projects: action.projects,
      };
    }
  }
};
```

actions.ts

```
import { IProject, IGotProjectsAction, IGettingProjectsAction } from "./types";
import agent from "../../agent";
import { ThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
import { ActionCreator, Dispatch } from "redux";

export const getProjectsActionCreator: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<
  // The type of the last action to be dispatched - will always be promise<T> for async actions
  Promise<IGotProjectsAction>,
  // The type for the data within the last action
  IProject[],
  // The type of the parameter for the nested function
  null,
  // The type of the last action to be dispatched
  IGotProjectsAction
>> = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    const gettingProjectsAction: IGettingProjectsAction = {
      type: "GettingProjects",
    };
    dispatch(gettingProjectsAction);
    const projects = await agent.Projects.list();
    const gotProjectsAction: IGotProjectsAction = {
      projects,
      type: "GotProjects",
    };
    return dispatch(gotProjectsAction);
  };
};
```

types.ts

```
import { Action } from "redux";

export interface IProject {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  number: string;
  status: number;
  description: string;
}

export interface IProjectState {
  projects: IProject[];
}

export interface IGettingProjectsAction extends Action<"GettingProjects"> {}

export interface IGotProjectsAction extends Action<"GotProjects"> {
  projects: IProject[];
}
export type ProjectActions = IGettingProjectsAction | IGotProjectsAction;
```

Projects.tsx

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from "react";
// import { IProjectState } from "../store/project/types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { IAppState } from "../store";

import { getProjectsActionCreator } from "../store/project/actions";
import { IGotProjectsAction, IProject } from "../store/project/types";
import { ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
import { AnyAction } from "redux";

interface IProps {
  getProjects: () => Promise<IGotProjectsAction>;
  projects: IProject[];
}

export const Projects: FC<IProps> = ({ getProjects, projects }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (store: IAppState) => {
  return {
    projects: store.project.projects,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, AnyAction>) => {
  return {
    getProjects: () => dispatch(getProjectsActionCreator()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Projects);
```

store/index.ts

```
import { projectReducer } from "./project/reducers";
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware, Store } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { IProject } from "./project/types";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  project: projectReducer,
});

interface IProjectState {
  readonly projects: IProject[];
}

export interface IAppState {
  project: IProjectState;
}

export function configureStore(): Store<IAppState> {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  return store;
}
```

agent.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { IProject } from "./store/project/types";
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:5000/api";

const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data;

const requests = {
  get: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(responseBody),
  post: (url: string, body: {}) => axios.post(url, body).then(responseBody),
  put: (url: string, body: {}) => axios.put(url, body).then(responseBody),
  delete: (url: string) => axios.delete(url).then(responseBody),
};

const Projects = {
  list: () => axios.get(`/projects`).then(responseBody),

  create: (project: IProject) => requests.post("/projects", project),
};

export default {
  Projects,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import { Projects } from "./features/Projects";
```

You are importing the named export. That is the component defined with this line:

```
export const Projects: FC<IProps> = ({ getProjects, projects }) => {
// etc
```

It is **not** the component defined with this line:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Projects);
```

Since you are importing the unconnected component, you need to provide all the props yourself, but you aren't, so typescript complains that you havn't given it the correct props.

Most likely, the fix is to import the connected component by changing your import to:

```
import Projects from "./features/Projects";
```

In my projects, i usually don't export the unconnected component *at all*. It's not intended to be used directly and so the only thing that exporting it does is make bugs like this possible.

Comment: Thanks so much! Save my day =D

Comment: I had the same issue with a component with a default export, which was re-exported from an index file. 


`export { default as MyComponent } from "./MyComponent"; // Not Working`

`import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";`

`export default MyComponent; // Works`

I don't understand what confuses typescript